# Check if plugin is active outside of admin screen

Tags: plugins

How can I check to see if a specific plugin is activated outside of the admin screen?  I know there is

```
is_plugin_active();
```

but according to the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active) this function is "only available from within the admin pages".  I however need to check if its active on any page load.

Comment: It depends on what you need to do, and what the plugin is. Ideally you wouldn't check if the plugin is active, you'd just check whether the class or function you need to use exists.

Comment: If you must use the function outside of admin pages, the Codex has an [example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active#Usage) to do that.

Comment: I'm not trying to use any of it's functions. I am adding onto its functionality with a new plugin, which won;t accomplish much of anything if the main plugin is not actually active.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're trying to do? If you're just using `add_action()` or `add_filter()` on a plugin's hooks then you don't need to check if it's active, because there's no harm adding functions to hooks that don't exist.

Comment: @Ryan, I hope you didn't misunderstand it when I said "the function"? And `is_plugin_active()` is only available from within admin pages because the file (`wp-admin/includes/plugin.php`) where the function is defined is only loaded on admin pages - on other pages, you need to manually load that file. And referring to Jacob's first comment, [here's an example](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/query-whether-woocommerce-is-activated/).